# designing Custom tabs using linearlayout with child elements(Imageview,Textview)

Tags: android

I am creating custom tabs which consists of seven tabs using linear layout with imageview and Textview(Child elements) and giving weight equaly to seven tabs. But  i need to set first tab width to remaining tabs so that it looks good.How to accompolish this. I am attaching screen shot for your kind reference.

**XML File**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="2dp"       
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
    android:scrollbarSize="1dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:background="#0668b1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:weightSum="7"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_wodetail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_wodetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_wodetails" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_wodetail"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="W/O Details"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_details"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_detail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_details"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_wodetail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Details"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_spares"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_spares"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_spares"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_spares"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Spares"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_tools"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_tools"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tools"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_tasks"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_tasks"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tasks"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_costs"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_costs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_costs"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_costs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Costs"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ll_tab_trades"
            android:background="#464646"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_icon_trades"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/wo_trades"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_icon_trades"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Trades"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                style="?android:attr/tabWidgetStyle"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv_wodetails"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="#000000">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:background="#000000">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wono"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Work Oder No"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wonoval"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_equipment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Equipment"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_equipmentval"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_equipmenthier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Equipment Hierarchy"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_equipmenthierval"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_jobdesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Job Description"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_jobdesc"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_instruction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Instruction"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <EditText
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:id="@+id/et_instruction"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_safetynotes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Safety Notes"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_safetynotes"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="18sp">
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wotype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="W/O Type"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wotypeval"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="WO TYPE"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Problem with your HorizontalScrollView... comment HorizontalScrollView and give width of child layout as 0dp ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply.if i comment the horizantalScrollView then all the child elements fit in to the window with reduced width. But that is not in this case as we need a first layout width set(W/O details) to the child elements with horizantal scrolling view.